# Seamless Kafka broker lookup

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to know is there a best way/practice to look up kafka broker from consumer/producer so that we don't need to change the consumer/producer code when application is moved from one environment (like Dev) to other environment (like ST,UAT,Prod). Currently all the example show consumer/producer need to be aware about IP address and port number of kafka broker in the cluster.

Thanks in advance for suggestions and views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use domain names in place of IP addresses in the Kafka configuration and then just change how the domain names resolve separately.

However these parameters should not be hard coded. They should be in properties files than can be edited without recompiling the apps